# How to run Jmeter Scripts with proxy for few request & without proxy for other

Tags: proxy, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have a requirement to run the Jmeter test with few request requires proxy and other without proxy .
For eg . Let's say I have the flow

1. Launch URL
2. Login
3. Run the web service call to get some id
4. Search
5. Logout

here all the request uses proxy except request 3 .

When I tried to open the Jmeter with `jmeter -H proxyserver -P port` all the request is passing except request 3 which throws error

```
 Data type ("text"|"bin"|""): text
Response code: 407
Response message: Proxy Authentication Required

Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 407 Proxy Authentication Required
Proxy-Authenticate: NTLM
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
```

Can anyone help me with this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have "Proxy Server" section under "Advanced" tab of the [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler where you can set different proxy settings for individual samplers

[image: JMeter per/sampler proxy settings]

You can also control HTTP Request sampler settings globally using [HTTP Request Defaults](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/why-its-so-important-use-jmeters-http-request-defaults) and override the settings if needed on sampler level